# The question regarding cerr cout and clog

Tags: c++, iostream

Can anybody explain the difference between cerr cout and clog and why does different objects are proposed?

I know the differences are as below:

1) cout can redirected but cerr can't

2) clog can use buffer.

I am confused about the point 2, I am grateful if anybody can elaborate it more.

Comment: Who says cerr can't be redirected?  I do it all the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffered output is typically much faster than unbuffered. So if you wanted to write a vast amount of data quickly to a log (but didn't care if it actually ended up there), you would use clog rather than cerr.

And all streams can normally be redirected, assuming a vaguely competent operating system, but this is outwith the C++ standard, which has no such concept as "redirection".

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit on the upside of cerr/non-buffered-io's upside - i.e. the stream is written even if something wrong happens right after the write operation.

Comment: @RaphaelSP That's what I meant by "(but didn't care if it actually ended up there)"

Comment: @Neil: the OP being seemingly confused about what buffering is, I think the formulation could be clearer :)

Answer (score 16):

Output can be buffered or unbuffered.  With buffered output, the implementation saves up all the output until it's convenient to write it to disk (or wherever).  This is nice and efficient, but if the program crashes some output will very likely be lost.  The implementation has to write unbuffered output to disk as it occurs, which can slow things down with lots of disk writes, but unless there's a program crash while it's being written it will be written to disk.

There's no real functional difference between standard output and standard error; they're just two different output streams that can be redirected separately.  The Unix philosophy of chaining tools together is that standard output will have the appropriate output to go into the input of the next tool, and this pretty much requires that there be a separate stream for error messages.

So, `cout` writes to standard output, and is buffered.  Use this for normal output.  `cerr` writes to the standard error stream, and is unbuffered.  Use this for error messages.  `clog` writes to the standard error stream, but is buffered.  This is useful for execution logging, as it doesn't interfere with standard output, but is efficient (at the cost that the end of the log is likely to be lost if the program crashes).

Answer (score 2):

Both can be redirected.
On most implementations cerr wouldn't be buffered, not sure if this is an official POSIX requirement, but it's crazy to have a buffered error stream.

The reason for having separate streams is from the unix philosophy that the output of one program is the input to the next. If 'ls' is going straight to 'sort' it's easier to have errors appear on the console than have to write sort to understand if an input is an error message or part of the text you wish to sort.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout-Screen output(stdout)
clog-Buffered output of standard error(stderr)
cerr-Standard error device output (stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the major reasons behind using buffered and unbuffered output can be observed by taking program crash as an example.

Consider a program which is outputting something into a log file. And suddenly the program crashed. You might be interested at this point in knowing what error made it crash but if you had used clog(buffered) for all logs and errors, you might not see all this information since those might still be in buffer when the program crashed hence information in buffer is also lost.

So in case of errors, `cerr` is mostly used as this is unbuffered and there cannot be any situation now when a major error is lost during a program crash just because it was in buffer.